# How can I view the content of deleted chat rooms that are linked to in moderator comments?

Tags: support, comments, chat

According to Monica Cellio's Meta SE answer to [Is chat room transcript link permanent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303600/is-chat-room-transcript-link-permanent?noredirect=1&lq=1) (from November 2017):

> rooms with little activity are auto-deleted, meaning that only **users with high rep (10k on that chat server) can see them**

But I can't figure out what the process is for seeing the content of deleted chat rooms.

I clicked on the comment containing the following link to a chat room:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45517/discussion-on-answer-by-graffito-what-does-dis-sho-am-good-mean-in-this-old-a).

But I only got the "page not found" page, which I assume means the chat room has been deleted. I can't figure out how to view the deleted content, even though I gather I should be able to since my ELU account has more than 10k rep.

I wondered at first if I had to log in separately for chat (since there was a "log in" button at the top right) but I seem to already be logged in.

[image]

Comment: If I click the "chat" link when I'm on EL&U, there's a button at the bottom of the "site" page that says "show frozen/deleted rooms"... Do you see that? I can then search for "discussion-on-answer-by-graffito" and find it.

Comment: @ColleenV: Yes. I can see frozen/deleted rooms from the ELU chat interface, but not when I try to go to the room using one of the links left when a moderator moves comments to chat.

Comment: Yeah, you have to wend your way through - can you see the transcript link? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/45517/2016/9/17

Comment: @ColleenV: Ah, I think I figured it out! The moderator comments didn't use https links, so they don't work now. That's annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your credentials are associated with the https version:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45517/discussion-on-answer-by-graffito-what-does-dis-sho-am-good-mean-in-this-old-a

And not the http one in the link.

Comment: I see. So are all of the links in the old moderator comments linking to deleted rooms broken now?

Comment: @sumelic Apparently. At least for viewing rooms that require higher privileges to view. Maybe MSE mentions this.

Comment: @sumelic Moderators can edit them to add the https - just flag them if you come across one.

Comment: @ColleenV Done.

Comment: @sumelic Is it in the chat room under your answer? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45518/discussion-on-answer-by-sumlic-what-does-dis-sho-am-good-mean-in-this-old-ad

Comment: @ColleenV: Yes! I must have just copied the wrong link. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Looks like this bug was fixed. If you have 10,000 reputation network-wide you will be able to see the now-deleted chatroom.

---

Original answer:

While tchrist is right about HTTP/HTTPS, there is actually a valid link to the chat room on the page. It's just hidden:

[image: "Object moved to here." under the header]

This is a bug and has already been reported on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302054/323179).